# BuddyPress - Edit Front-End User Profiles as WP Admin

Tags: wordpress, admin, edit, buddypress

We have a WordPress site with a BuddyPress community, currently to edit all areas of the users' profiles on the front-end we have to ask them for their login, I would like to be able to edit these when logged in as a WP admin.

I've seen various posts about change requests from a few years ago but nothing detailing how it can be achieved.

Comment: By default, Admins can edit all areas of any profile on the front end. And back end.  So your issue is particular to your install... perhaps due to another plugin or your theme.

Comment: Possibly disabled by previous developer, where would I look for that?

Comment: Maybe theme/functions.php  Maybe bp-custom.php  Maybe a plugin.

Comment: I've found some remove actions in functions.php but they relate to various WP admin menu items (logo, user menu, etc.). Tried re-enabling them all but I still don't see the BuddyPress stuff.

Comment: I get the 404 page when attempting to edit a user's Buddypress profile when logged in as anyone other than them, including admin.